# InputField のコンテンツタイプをパスワードにした時にテキスト内容が取得できない

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

パスワードを入力するInputFieldを作成し、コンテンツタイプをパスワードにして
入力した文字を取得した場合、たとえば `1234` と入力した場合、表示は `****` になります。

そしてそのデータを取得した場合も `1234` ではなく `****` になってしまうのですが、何か取り方がおかしいのでしょうか？

```
[SerializeField] Text m_PasswordText;

//入力完了した時に呼ばれる関数
public void OnEndEdit()
{
    Debug.Log("m_PasswordText=" + m_PasswordText.text);
}
```

Comment: この記事が該当するのでは？ [Text of Password type InputField only gets asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56532028/9014308) TextコンポーネントのtextプロパティではなくInputFieldコンポーネント自体のtextプロパティを使用する、ということらしいですね。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。そういうことだったんですね。前のプログラムの流れからなんとなくTextとしてしまってました。ちゃんとInputFieldにしないといけなかったのですね。